# Regex Optional Conditional Exact Match?

Tags: regex

I have a Regex that looks like this:

```
(?<Number>\d{3})-?(?<Hand>R?L?)[-\s]?(?<Description>.*?)?(?<ShnOpp>SHN|OPP)?$
```

With some sample data:

```
104-RL-BLAH BLA SHN
104-RL FOO OPP
102-RL-BAR WL74
102-BAR WL74
102-R-BAR WL74 SHN
102-R-BAR WL74 OPP
```

So, the named group `Hand` can either contain `RL|R|L|{Blank}`.

But, if and only if, `Hand="RL"` do I want to match `ShnOpp` with `SHN|OPP`, otherwise just leave it as part of the description.  So, can I do a literal `IF` condition within my regex?

Either my Googling skills failed me or maybe you just can't do it, but I'd love to be proved wrong.

Here's a link to a working sample: https://regex101.com/r/wGghbV/2

Comment: Are you using it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a conditional to check that a certain group captured one exact text, however it is possible to use a conditional here by adding a new group that only matches `RL` like:

```
(?<Number>\d{3})-?(?<Hand>(?<RL>RL)|[RL]?)[ \-]?(?<Description>.*?)[ \-]?(?(RL)(?<ShnOpp>SHN|OPP)?)$
```

Your updated sample: https://regex101.com/r/wGghbV/3